# Active MQ connection issue

Tags: java, activemq-classic, wso2, wso2-esb

Hi am working on wso2 esb and using Active MQ for message queue.

I have a simple service to place a message in which it call custom java class where it creates a tcp connection and drops a message in queue.

Java code looks like below

```
   package in.esb.custommediators;

import javax.jms.*; 

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;


import org.apache.synapse.ManagedLifecycle;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.core.SynapseEnvironment;
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

import org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.NhttpConstants;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class JMSStoreMediator extends AbstractMediator implements
ManagedLifecycle { 

    Connection connection;
    Session session;

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext msgCtx) { 

        log.info("LogLocation = "+getClass().getName()+",ProxyName = "+msgCtx.getProperty("proxy.name")+
                ",Usercode = "+msgCtx.getProperty("usercode")+",Clientid = "+msgCtx.getProperty("clientid")+
                ",requestMsgId = "+msgCtx.getProperty("requestMsgId")+",Position = START"); 


         try {
             boolean topic=false;
            String jmsuri=""+msgCtx.getProperty("jmsuri");
            String t=""+msgCtx.getProperty("topic");
            if(t.isEmpty()){
                topic=false;
            }
            else {
                topic=Boolean.valueOf(t);
            }
            ConnectionFactory factory= new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(jmsuri);
            connection = factory.createConnection();
                connection.start();

            log.info("LogLocation = "+getClass().getName()+",JMS connection created :"+connection);
            this.session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Destination destination=null;
            if(!topic)destination= session.createQueue(""+msgCtx.getProperty("jmsqueue"));
            else destination= session.createTopic(""+msgCtx.getProperty("jmsqueue"));
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

            String xml = ""+msgCtx.getEnvelope().getBody().toStringWithConsume();

            if(topic){

                JSONObject obj=XML.toJSONObject(xml);
                JSONObject ar=obj.getJSONObject("soapenv:Body");
                ar.remove("xmlns:soapenv");
                xml=ar.toString();
            }
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(xml);
            producer.send(message);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            log.info("LogLocation = "+getClass().getName()+",Error in storing message in JMS stacktrace is :"+e.toString()+"message is :"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

            ((Axis2MessageContext) msgCtx).setProperty(NhttpConstants.HTTP_SC, 500);
            handleException("Error while storing in the message store", msgCtx);

        }
        finally {
            try {
                session.close();
                if (connection!=null){
                    log.info("LogLocation = "+getClass().getName()+",JMS connection closing :"+connection);
                    connection.close();
                }

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                log.info("LogLocation = "+getClass().getName()+",Error in closing JMS connection stacktrace is :"+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init(SynapseEnvironment arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

when i call this service to send a message in queue below logs get generated.

```
[2017-07-29 11:18:35,962]  INFO - JMSStoreMediator LogLocation = in.esb.custommediators.JMSStoreMediator,JMS connection created :ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:my-desktop-36442-1501307315570-3:1,clientId=ID:my-desktop-36442-1501307315570-2:1,started=true}
```

As of now every thing is working good , But when two users try to submit message at the same tire some strange thing happen as shown below

```
[2017-07-29 11:43:11,948]  INFO - JMSStoreMediator LogLocation = in.my.esb.custommediators.JMSStoreMediator,JMS connection created :ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:my-desktop-36442-1501307315570-11:1,clientId=ID:my-desktop-36442-1501307315570-10:1,started=false}
[2017-07-29 11:43:11,963]  INFO - JMSStoreMediator LogLocation = in.my.esb.custommediators.JMSStoreMediator,JMS connection created :ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:my-desktop-36442-1501307315570-11:1,clientId=ID:my-desktop-36442-1501307315570-10:1,started=true}

[2017-07-29 11:43:12,068]  INFO - JMSStoreMediator LogLocation = in.my.esb.custommediators.JMSStoreMediator,Error in closing JMS connection stacktrace is :org.apache.activemq.ConnectionClosedException: The connection is already closed
```

Active MQ is creating two connections but using one connection for both the calls and that one connection is getting closed in one of the service call  and throwing already closed error in the other service call and  the other connection is waiting forever in the connection list of active mq with active status true as shown in the below image and this is also seen in the ESB thread list.

[image]

This kind of connections pileup and causing hangs ESB server. Even if i reset this connections from Active MQ ESB threads carry this connection info and only after a restart of ESB the problem get fixed.

Comment: Where is initialization of connection variable ? It looks like that reference to connection available in another thread

Comment: Is this custom mediator implementation? Can you provide full code of class?
It is obvious some multi-threading issues in here

Comment: Hi @simar yes am using a custom mediator ,i have edited my question with full custom class which am using and it has some multithread issue as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read article [Extending the Functionality of WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus - Part 1](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/06/article-extending-the-functionality-of-wso2-enterprise-service-bus-part-1/#threadsafety) ?

Important part is **Threading Safety**. It states, each mediator, including custom, is shared between incoming messages. I recommend to move class variables

```
Connection connection;
Session session;
```

to method *public boolean mediate(MessageContext msgCtx)* since local variables are thread safe

```
public class JMSStoreMediator extends AbstractMediator implements
ManagedLifecycle {     

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext msgCtx) { 
             Connection connection;
             Session session;
    ....
    ....
    rest the same
```

Comment: made changes as per your suggestion and checked but dint helped same problem.Ill go through the article.